# Мерцание при переходе между сценами при анимации

Tags: android, анимация, transition

Всем доброго времени суток!
Вопрос в следующем - при переходе между сценами с использованием TransitionManager происходит непонятное мерцание. Создается впечатление, что старая сцена полностью удаляется, а новая добавляется только через небольшой промежуток времени (порядка 20 мс). При этом мерцание только при прямом переходе, обратный переход проходит плавно.

Вот код инициализации самих сцен:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSceneLogin = Scene.getSceneForLayout(mSceneRoot, R.layout.activity_login_scene_autorization, this);
    mSceneRegistrationP1 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(mSceneRoot, R.layout.activity_login_scene_registration_page_1, this);
    mSceneRegistrationP2 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(mSceneRoot, R.layout.activity_login_scene_registration_page_2, this);
}
```

Код анимации между первой (mSceneLogin) и второй (mSceneRegistrationP1) сценами:

```
@Override
public void animateSceneRegistration(int pageNumber) {
    TransitionSet mSet = new TransitionSet();
    mSet.setDuration(250);
    mSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    mSet.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER);

    ChangeBounds logo = new ChangeBounds();
    logo.addTarget(R.id.app_bar);
    logo.addTarget(R.id.logo);
    logo.addTarget(R.id.title);
    logo.addTarget(R.id.subtitle);
    logo.addTarget(R.id.diagonal);

    Fade fade = new Fade(Fade.IN);
    fade.addTarget(R.id.scene_body);
    fade.addTarget(R.id.title);
    fade.addTarget(R.id.subtitle);

    mSet.addTransition(logo);
    mSet.addTransition(fade);

    mSet.addListener(new TransitionListenerAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(@NonNull Transition transition) {
            setupSceneRegistration(pageNumber);
        }
    });

    if(pageNumber == 1) {
        getPresenter().getPresentationModel().setFormMode(Constants.ACTIVITY_LOGIN_STATUS_REGISTER_FIRST);
        TransitionManager.go(mSceneRegistrationP1, mSet);
    } else {
        getPresenter().getPresentationModel().setFormMode(Constants.ACTIVITY_LOGIN_STATUS_REGISTER_SECOND);
        TransitionManager.go(mSceneRegistrationP2, mSet);
    }
}
```

Лайоут сцены 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout
    android:id="@+id/diagonal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:diagonal_angle="10"
    app:diagonal_gravity="right|top">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWindowsBackground">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="72dp"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/iin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Login.HintTextAppearance"
                    app:errorEnabled="true" >

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="830831301465"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/base_text_size_large"
                        android:hint="@string/la_fields_iin"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_visibility_btn_selector"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="123456"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/base_text_size_large"
                        android:hint="@string/la_fields_password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/remember"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:text="@string/la_check_remember_iin"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/base_text_size_medium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    android:id="@+id/btn.login"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_button_primary"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
                    app:rv_color="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    app:rv_rippleDuration="150">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/base_text_size_medium"
                        android:text="@string/button_sign_in" />

                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    android:id="@+id/btn.register"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

                    android:background="@drawable/bg_button_secondary"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
                    app:rv_color="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:rv_rippleDuration="150">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/base_text_size_medium"
                        android:text="@string/button_sign_up" />

                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app.bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:elevation="5dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.ToolbarTitleTextAppearance"
        app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.ToolbarSubTitleTextAppearance" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@mipmap/nsk_logo_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:text="@string/la_caption_activity_title"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        tools:text="Авторизация"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Лайоут сцены 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout
    android:id="@+id/diagonal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    app:diagonal_angle="10"
    app:diagonal_gravity="right|top">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWindowsBackground">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="72dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/iin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:errorEnabled="true" >

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="830831301465"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/base_text_size_medium"
                        android:hint="@string/la_fields_iin"
                        android:inputType="number" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:errorEnabled="true" >

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/base_text_size_medium"
                        android:text="didenko.p@nsk.kz"
                        android:hint="@string/la_fields_email"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/email.confirm"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:errorEnabled="true" >

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/base_text_size_medium"
                        android:text="didenko.p@nsk.kz"
                        android:hint="@string/la_fields_emailconfirm"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_visibility_btn_selector"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" >

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="123456"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/base_text_size_medium"
                        android:hint="@string/la_fields_password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/password.confirm"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_visibility_btn_selector"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" >

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="123456"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/base_text_size_medium"
                        android:hint="@string/la_fields_passconfirm"
                        android:inputType="textPassword" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    android:id="@+id/btn.register"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_button_secondary"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
                    app:rv_color="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:rv_rippleDuration="150">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/base_text_size_medium"
                        android:text="@string/button_sign_up_more" />

                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app.bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:elevation="5dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.ToolbarTitleTextAppearance"
        app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.ToolbarSubTitleTextAppearance" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/nsk_logo_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:text="@string/la_caption_activity_title_reg"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        tools:text="Регистрация" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:text="@string/la_caption_activity_subtitle_page_1"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        tools:text="Страница 1" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Что было сделано:

1. Пробовал использовать компонент transitions-everywhere - безрезультатно.
2. Пробовал переделать лайоуты и уйти от использования CoordinatorLayout -

безрезультатно.

Подскажите куда копать?

ЗЫ: Анимация непосредственно в сцене выполняется нормально. Проблема только в скачке при смене сцены.